# Telebot - библиотека для разработки бота в телеграмм

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Начал писать своего бота, но столкнулся с проблемой, бот не видит, что написал пользователь. Либо видит, но ничего не выводит, хотя по сути должен. Я думаю, что мне следует указать, с какого момента он должен это видеть, по этому - 12 строка, где начинается логическая проверка

```
import telebot,sqlite3,main,time,main2
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot("Токен")
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start", "help"])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f"Привет,<b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>", parse_mode='html')
    markupyear = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    yearbtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('2023')
    yearbtn2 = types.KeyboardButton('2022')
    markupyear.add(yearbtn1, yearbtn2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Какакого года ты хочешь посмотреть аниме?", reply_markup=markupyear, parse_mode='html')
    if message.text == "2023":
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Экшен', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2023/genres-is-action/apply")
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Фэнтези', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2023/genres-is-fantasy/apply")
        btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Драма', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2023/genres-is-drama/apply")
        btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Приключения', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2023/genres-is-adventure/apply")
        btn5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Романтика', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2023/genres-is-romance/apply")
        markup.add(btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Теперь выбери жанр", reply_markup=markup, parse_mode='html')
    elif message.text == "2022":
        markup2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn12022 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Экшен', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2022-to-2022/genres-is-action/apply")
        btn22022 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Фэнтези', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2022-to-2022/genres-is-fantasy/apply")
        btn32022 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Драма', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2022-to-2022/genres-is-drama/apply")
        btn42022 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Приключения', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2022-to-2022/genres-is-adventure/apply")
        btn52022 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Романтика', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2022-to-2022/genres-is-romance/apply")
        markup2.add(btn12022,btn22022,btn32022,btn42022,btn52022)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Теперь выбери жанр", reply_markup=markup2, parse_mode='html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Бот не видит Ваших сообщений, потому что вы не поставили пустой hanlder, который будет обрабатывать сообщения от пользователя:

```
@bot.message_handler() #пустой hanlder улавливает все сообщения пользователя и в зависимости от условий обрабатывает их
 if message.text == "2023":
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Экшен', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2023/genres-is-action/apply")
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Фэнтези', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2023/genres-is-fantasy/apply")
        btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Драма', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2023/genres-is-drama/apply")
        btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Приключения', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2023/genres-is-adventure/apply")
        btn5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Романтика', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2023/genres-is-romance/apply")
        markup.add(btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Теперь выбери жанр", reply_markup=markup, parse_mode='html')
    elif message.text == "2022":
        markup2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn12022 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Экшен', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2022-to-2022/genres-is-action/apply")
        btn22022 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Фэнтези', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2022-to-2022/genres-is-fantasy/apply")
        btn32022 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Драма', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2022-to-2022/genres-is-drama/apply")
        btn42022 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Приключения', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2022-to-2022/genres-is-adventure/apply")
        btn52022 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Романтика', url="https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2022-to-2022/genres-is-romance/apply")
        markup2.add(btn12022,btn22022,btn32022,btn42022,btn52022)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Теперь выбери жанр", reply_markup=markup2, parse_mode='html')
```